# Ethernet interface EEPROM failure after thunderstorm; any way to recover?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

During a thunderstorm, two times in a row the ground fault circuit breaker tripped and a number of devices, including my NAS lost power. After the second time one of the ethernet interfaces of my NAS won't come online anymore.

The hardware is detected, but the interface won't come online. Oddly, the MAC address has also changed. Previously the may address was `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:EF` (censored) but now it is a completely different address.

In my `dmesg` I noticed the following:

```
iegbe 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
iegbe 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
iegbe: 0000:01:00.0: iegbe_probe: The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid
iegbe: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -5
iegbe 0000:01:01.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
iegbe 0000:01:01.0: setting latency timer to 64
iegbe: eth0: iegbe_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
iegbe 0000:01:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
iegbe 0000:01:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
iegbe: 0000:01:02.0: iegbe_reset: Hardware Error
iegbe: eth1: iegbe_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
iegbe: eth0: iegbe_watchdog: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex
```

You can see `The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid` followed by `Hardware Error`. Other devices in my home are not damaged, and the other interface is functioning correctly so I suspect the failure must be caused by the power failure rather than a lightning strike.

The interfaces are (were) from hardware perspective completely the same, other than the different MAC address.

Since the other interface is fine, how (if) is it possible to restore the EEPROM of the faulty interface based on the other interface? I have serial terminal access to the NAS, so I can take both interfaces offline if required.

Comment: What company made that ethernet interface device? Isn't it a good idea to ask them the same question?

Comment: `iegbe` apparently means "Intel(R) EP80579 for Embedded Applications Gigabit". Intel is not an easy organisation to contact.